# Ruby - Sort by date in ascending order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I am developing a roster planning system by using ruby on rails.

I have a page that let the user create their roster (new.html.erb) and a page that show which date has created a roster (all.html.erb)

all.html.erb

```
<% @rosters.each do |roster| %>
Date: <%= roster.date %>
```

rosters_controller.rb

```
def all
@rosters = Roster.all
end
```

The page shows all the rosters' date according to user created time.
For example:

> Date: 23/3/2017 
>  Date: 24/3/2017 
>  Date: 27/3/2017 
>  Date: 26/3/2017 
>  Date: 25/3/2017

I would like to show the roster sort by date in ascending order. 
As below

> Date: 23/3/2017 
>   Date: 24/3/2017  
>   Date: 25/3/2017  
>   Date: 26/3/2017  
>   Date: 27/3/2017

How can I show the date in ascending order?

Comment: What you have tried?

Answer (score 2):

Change your method to:

```
def all
 @rosters = Roster.order(date: :asc)
end
```

Comment: Thank You! The problem is fixed.

Comment: you are welcome @Jeff

Comment: no need for `:asc` because it is default.